# Different values for Tag Badge Progress bar and track next badge pop up window

Tags: bug, badges, badge-progress

In my stack overflow profile I can see different values for tag badge score in progress bar compared to the value in track next badge pop up window. Here are the screenshots.
I have seen related links to my question but I am seeing 43 value for over a month now while in links it is said that it gets updated in a day or so.
**Progress Bar in Profile**

[image: Progress Bar in Profile]

**Progress Bar in Dialog**
[image: Progress Bar in Dialog]

Comment: @honk I read that link. Isn't this issue solved yet?

Comment: @honk I am seeing 43 value for score for over a month now. And in that link it is said that it will get updated next day.