# Profile Page Track Next Badge Showing Wrong Number

Tags: bug, profile-page, tag-badges, badge-progress

On my profile page, when I set it to track next badge, it tells me I am at 
248/400 for score on the silver python badge.  Meanwhile, the popup dialogue that lets me pick which one to track says my python score is 620/400.

620 is my score for python answers.  248 is slightly less than my score for python questions.  Is it possible that the score under track next badge on the profile page is pulling from the wrong source?

MODERATOR NOTE: before marking this as a duplicate, please note.  I have read the posts in the following three questions:
[Tag score is shown incorrectly in the next badge tracker section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305636/tag-score-is-shown-incorrectly-in-the-next-badge-tracker-section)
[Tag Badge progress values inconsistent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306800/tag-badge-progress-values-inconsistent)
[Different values for Tag Badge Progress bar and track next badge pop up window](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327485/different-values-for-tag-badge-progress-bar-and-track-next-badge-pop-up-window)
The conclusion of these questions is that this is a caching problem.  **What I am reporting is not a caching problem.**  248 hasn't been my score for python answers in well over a year.

Comment: Keep in mind the badge is about answers, while your tag score is for both questions and answers. You have a lot of both which might confuse the numbers you're looking at.

Comment: Hmm... I thought maybe somehow your self-answers weren't being counted in the total, however you have a little over 390 points as votes to answers you provided to your own questions, and 620 - 390 < 248, so that can't be it.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't underestimating your cache? (mandatory joke disclaimer)

Comment: @rene There is definitely a bug because there is inconsistency between what is shown on the profile page for "Next tag badge" and what is shown on the modal for "Chose which tag badge to track".  I suspect that the "Chose which tag badge to track" is implemented correctly and "Next tag badge" has the bug.

Comment: @AndréKool "There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors." - Jeff Atwood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this got fixed.  Thanks SO team.